# How to get number of iterations in EM-algorithm using R mclust gaussian mixture model

Tags: r, gaussian-mixture-distribution, expectation-maximization

I am clustering data using the `mclust` function from the R `mclust` package. I am struggling to get the number of iterations the EM algorithm in the Gaussian Mixture model used to cluster (context: complexity thoughts).

I have consulted [this question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26549145/r-using-mclust-for-gaussian-mixture-mode-how-to-get-number-of-iterations), but it does not help me much and is not fairly recent.

Is there any way the function `mclust` can output the number the iterations it employed without specifying a maximum number of iterations to approximate it?

Comment: Consider trying ```sklearn.mixture.GaussianMixture``` in Python instead. it has an attribute to extract the EM algorithm iterations called ```.n_iter_``` https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.mixture.GaussianMixture.html#sklearn.mixture.GaussianMixture

Comment: @develarist, thank you very much. I was hoping I could stay in R. Yet the `sklearn.mixture.GaussianMixture` reads very promising. It is definitely an option to run the relevant algorithms in python and extract the number of iterations there.

Answer (score 1):

Not so sure you can get it back from the `Mclust` object, unless you hack it to return the iterations.

If you really need the iteration numbers, you go down and run your model using `em` function, below I adapt something from the vignette:

```
# provide a provisional cluster for E step using hclust 
# you can use kmeans too

z = cutree(hclust(dist(iris[,-5])),5)

msEst <- mstep(modelName = "EEE", data = iris[,-5], 
                    z = unmap(z))

mdl = em(modelName = msEst$modelName, data = iris[,-5],
parameters = msEst$parameters)

attr(mdl,"info")
  iterations        error 
4.800000e+01 9.992635e-06
```

You can see the iteration number is stored under `attr(..,"info")`, but somehow this is not returned in the `Mclust` object. You gotta try and see if this will work for the clustering you are doing